# What is the difference between the stockpile techs in Endless Legend?

Tags: endless-legend

In Endless Legend, there are two technologies related to stockpiles:

- **Unskilled Labor** (3rd era, 1200 production cost per stockpile)
- **Organized Labor** (4th era, 2500 production cost per stockpile)

Both technologies allow you to create the same types of stockpiles, so what is the difference between these? I'm sure there's a difference, but on paper the tier 4 technology looks inferior since it costs more production per stockpile. (which can't be right)

Comment: I think they cost more, but when you apply them, they also give you a bigger bonus.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The stockpiles provided by **Organized Labor** are significantly more efficient in terms of  production cost-to-yield.

When I tested on Easy difficulty, I got these results:

```
          | Cost (Production) | Yield | Cost / Yield (Lower is better)
----------------------------------------------------
Unskilled |   1200            |  175  |   6.9
----------------------------------------------------
Organized |   2500            |  875  |   2.9
```

As you can see, Organized Labor provides more than double the production/science/food as the corresponding Unskilled Labor-level stockpile per point of production spent on the stockpile. (The numbers adjust somewhat on other difficulties, but the principle will be the same)

It is also worth noting that once you complete researching Organized Labor, *all your existing stockpiles* will upgrade to the improved yield.

Comment: Do the Necrophage stockpiles benefit from the research?

Comment: @Annan Just found out from reading the forum that it does not. " It does not scale with necrophages food stockpile, because it is not a 'food' stockpile, it's a "recycling" stockpile."(Tigregalis)

Comment: So...the most efficient stockpile is one that is built by a faction with Unskilled Labor, but consumed by a faction with Organized Labor...at a Cost/Yield ratio of 1.37

Comment: @TheodoreMurdock Yes, but your window of opportunity is limited. Also note that the upgrade-existing-stockpiles mechanic also applies to the ones you can buy from the marketplace, which yield a measly 25 if you don't have any stockpile tech yet. So depending on the gold/production tradeoff it might be most efficient to buy stockpiles from the marketplace early on, and hold onto them until you have Organized Labor.

Comment: @Aurelius I suspect that from the market's perspective, a stockpile is a stockpile, and the price changes based on sales and purchases, without respect to the two skills. In a multiplayer game, everyone has access to the market, but the techs are per player. This suggests that players that research Unskilled but not Organized Labor have a competitive advantage in producing stockpiles to sell for dust, while those with Organized Labor have a competitive advantage in consuming them from the marketplace.